# C++ Call of overloaded function is ambiguous

Tags: c++, overloading, ambiguous

I am trying to make a code applying function overload.
The two functions are supposed to be distinguished by the type of input and output variables. (The user either inputs an element symbol (std::string) and gets the atomic number (int) or vice-versa).
I tried to apply this to my code, but I get the error message that the call of the overloaded function is ambiguous. I don't understand what I could change; as I have my code now, I am converting the variables applying to the given case to the correct type, so why is it still ambiguous?

The error I get is:

> /var/lib/cxrun/projectfiles/main.cpp: In function 'int main()': /var/lib/cxrun/projectfiles/main.cpp:40:48: error: call of overloaded 'lookup(int)' is ambiguous    (std::string)output = lookup(std::stoi(input));
> ^ /var/lib/cxrun/projectfiles/main.cpp:25:13: note: candidate: 'std::__cxx11::string lookup(int)'  std::string lookup(int atomicNumber);
> ^~~~~~ /var/lib/cxrun/projectfiles/main.cpp:12:15: note: candidate: 'std::__cxx11::string exercises::lookup(int)'    std::string lookup(int atomicNumber);
> ^~~~~~ /var/lib/cxrun/projectfiles/main.cpp:45:48: error: call of overloaded 'lookup(std::__cxx11::string)' is ambiguous  std::stoi(output) = lookup((std::string)input);
> ^ /var/lib/cxrun/projectfiles/main.cpp:24:5: note: candidate: 'int lookup(std::__cxx11::string)'  int lookup(std::string name);
> ^~~~~~ /var/lib/cxrun/projectfiles/main.cpp:11:7: note: candidate: 'int exercises::lookup(std::__cxx11::string)'    int lookup(std::string name);
> ^~~~~~

```
// use functions from the standard library (like cout)
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

// to avoid name-clashes, create a namespace
namespace exercises
{
  // add elements + lookup functionality
  int lookup(std::string name);
  std::string lookup(int atomicNumber);
  
} /* end of namespace exercises */

// I want to use the functions from our new namespace...
using namespace exercises;

//arrays
std::string t[4] = {"H", "Rh", "Cl", "C"};
int s[4] = {1, 45, 17, 6};

//Function declarations
int lookup(std::string name);
std::string lookup(int atomicNumber);

int main(void)
{
//declare input and output variable as string temporarily 
std::string input;
std::string output;

//lookup something
std::cout << "Enter element or atomic number to look up:" << std::endl;
std::cin >> input;

//if input is atomic number, make it of type integer to match function input type
if(std::isdigit(input[0])){
  //std::stoi(input);
  (std::string)output = lookup(std::stoi(input));
}
//else, make output of type integer
else{
  //std::stoi(output);
  std::stoi(output) = lookup((std::string)input);
};
//std::string output;
//output = lookup(input);

if(std::isdigit(output[0])){
  if(std::stoi(output) == 1){
    std::cout << "Invalid input!" << std::endl;
  };
  return 0;
};

if(output == "error"){
  std::cout << "Invalid input!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

//print output
std::cout << "|**Sample Input**|**Sample Output**|" << std::endl;
std::cout << "|" << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(16) << "|" << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(16) << "|" << std::endl;
std::cout << "|" << std::left << std::setw(16) << input << "|" << std::left << std::setw(16) << output << "|" << std::endl;

return 0;
}

//function definition element symbol --> atomic number
int lookup(std::string input){
  int output; 
  //check if input is valid, ie if exists in array t
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<sizeof(t); i++){
    if(input == t[i]){
      output = s[i];
      
  return output;
    };
  };
  output = 1;
  return output;
}
  
//function definition atomic number --> element symbol
std::string lookup(int input){
  //check if input is valid, ie if exists in array s
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<sizeof(s); i++){
    if(input == s[i]){
      std::string output;
      output = t[i];
      
  return output;
    };
  };
  std::string output = "error";
  return output;
}
```

Comment: Post the complete error. And also add comment in your code where you're getting this error.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @JesperJuhl How can the debugger be used here when the code doesn't even compile?

Comment: `int main(void)` - just `int main()` will do. C++ is *not* C.

Comment: @JasonLiam Right. I'll still leave the comment in place, since I think OP is going to need it eventually.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes it will once the code starts running(executing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you declare the functions in the namespace `excercises`, then you add `using namespace exercises;`, after that you declare them again in the default namespace. Due to the using-directive, the compiler does not know, which version of the declaration to refer to, the ones declared inside the namespace or the ones declared in the default namespace.

The functions declared in the namespace `exercises` remain undefined, you only define the ones in the default namespace.

Try solving the problem first without namespace usage, then add the namespace but do **not** use the `using namespace` declaration.

Comment: Notable: once this is address, this: `std::stoi(output) = lookup((std::string)input);` is nonsense, and will need some self-explanation.

Comment: @WhozCraig in fact, I first didn't have that, so I was simply saying "output = lookup(input);", since in fact the variable types should be clear already by then? But then I wondered if I might have to explicitly cast the variable types to make the function call ambiguous, so I changed it to that.

Comment: @treuss Oh, now I see! Thank you very much. I didn't realise that I need to put the function definitions into the namespace too, but that completely makes sense. I now moved the function declarations as well as the two arrays to the namespace and now my code compiled! Thank you very much!